# Interchange of limits and infinite sums

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of functions $[-1,1]\to \mathbb R$ and suppose that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(h)$ converges pointwise in $[-1,1]$ to a function $f(h)$. Furthermore, suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(h)=0$ uniformly in $h\in[-1,1]$. Is then the following true?

\begin{equation}
\lim_{h\to 0} f(h)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lim_{h\to 0} f_n(h)
\end{equation}

Here we are assuming that all the limits exist. If this is not true, I would like to hear about interesting examples.

Comment: My hunch is that the answer is no, this feels like an opportunity for the usual pointwise-convergence-being-insufficient counterexamples to apply; uniformity of $f_n(h)\to 0$ doesn't, I don't think, give us a sufficiently uniform bound on the series tails $\sum_{n\ge m}f_n$

Comment: The answer is NO.  This is surely a duplicate?

Comment: @GEdgar And a counter-example is...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another example.  (One may see my first example, and comment that "the functions $f_n$ are weird".  What if we only use "normal" funtions?)

The Fourier series...
$$
f(t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4}{\pi(2n-1)}\sin(\pi(2n-1)t)
$$
[image: A]
This sum is a "square wave":  $f(t) = 0$ if $t$ is an integer, otherwise $f(t) = 1$ if the greatest integer $\lfloor t \rfloor$ is even and $f(t) = -1$ if
$\lfloor t \rfloor$ is odd.

Note,
$$
\left|\frac{4}{\pi(2n-1)}\sin(\pi(2n-1)t)\right| \le
\frac{4}{\pi(2n-1)}
$$
so this converges to zero uniformly as $n \to \infty$.

But of course
$$
 \lim_{t\to 0^+}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{4}{\pi(2k-1)}\sin(\pi(2n-1)t)
=\lim_{t\to 0^+} f(t) = 1
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{4}{\pi(2k-1)}\sin(\pi(2n-1)t)
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty 0 = 0
$$

Answer (score 2):

An example, easy to think of ...
Write $\mathbf1_E$ for the indicator function (characteristic function) of a set $E$.
Define

\begin{align}
f_1 &= \mathbf1_{(0,1]}
\\
f_2 = f_3 &= -\frac12\mathbf1_{(1/2,1]}
\\
f_4=f_5=f_6=f_7 &= -\frac14\mathbf1_{(1/4,1/2]}
\\
f_8=\cdots=f_{15} &= -\frac18\mathbf1_{(1/8,1/4]}
\\
\vdots
\end{align}
First, note thet $f_n$ converges uniformly to $0$.
Next, compute the pointwise sum of the series $f(t) = \sum f_n(t)$:

\begin{align}
\text{If } \frac12<t\le 1 &\text{, then } f(t) = 1-\frac12-\frac12 = 0
\\
\text{If } \frac14<t\le \frac12 &\text{, then } 
f(t) = 1-\frac14-\frac14-\frac14-\frac14 = 0
\\
\text{If } \frac18<t\le \frac14 &\text{, then } 
f(t) = 1-\frac18-\frac18-\frac18-\frac18-\frac18-\frac18-\frac18-\frac18 = 0
\\
&\vdots
\\
\text{for all } t \in \mathbb R, &\;f(t)=0.
\end{align}
Therefore, we have
$$
\lim_{t \to 0^+}\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(t) = 0,
\tag1$$

Now consider the limits of the terms $f_n(t)$ as $t \to 0^+$ ...
We have $\lim_{t \to 0^+}f_1(t) = 1$, and for $n \ge 2$ we have
$\lim_{t \to 0^+}f_n(t) = 0$ .  So
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lim_{t \to 0^+}f_n(t) = 1,
\tag2$$

Our conclusion compares $(1)$ and $(2)$.